# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011

Tags: discussion, promotion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/808/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- open source wordpress plugins
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/501).

Answer (score 14):

[image: Attend a WordCamp near you!]

Comment: I guess you're not allowed to use the official wp logo..

Comment: What do you mean by that? The logo came from http://wordpress.org/about/logos/ which contains the statement _When you need the official WordPress logo for a web site or publication, please use one of the following. These are the real deal._

Comment: oh, ok. i _heared_ something like that (and that's why i said *i guess*)

Comment: Since this specific ad points to WordCamp site that is official resource which promotes WP I imagine usage of official logo is allowed and appropriate. See http://wordpressfoundation.org/trademark-policy/

Answer (score 13):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Fun. Fun! More fun!!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: We Never Fail]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Visit WordPress Answers on Twitter]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Object relationship development proposal on WordPress Trac]

Comment: I am not so wild about this image. I think it would be clearer to show what it could look like in the UI. Maybe ask scribu if we can use [a screenshot of his plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/screenshots/), with an overlay text like "Help use create a standardized way to create links between posts, files, users, ..."

Comment: @Jan Fabry feel free to create your own version :) there is no rule that some ad should be canonical and if it doesn't get enough votes it won't be displayed anyway

Comment: @Jan Fabry - The Object Relationships plugin is more about defining a defacto standard database schema and less about UI.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately calling it "post relationships" is confusing since it's for much more than posts. Also, since the discussion is happening in an forum that requires a *(freely available)* login it's probably best not to promote on WPSE, at least not until there's a way to promote it via a publicly visible site.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I think of it as promoting idea and development, not end product. While I put the link to your specific comment as most recent development, the link in general is to trac ticket with considerable history. If there isn't enough interest at moment - there simply would be no votes for ad to reach showing threshold.