# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/community-promotion-ads-2013)

A new year means, a new start of ads! And hopefully better schedule adherence. Which we're doing by switching to a yearly cycle anyway.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Users will provide images of the advertisements, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- open source wordpress plugins
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/808).

Comment: Put images and links to what in answers? Do you mean images/links specific to the answer(ie. business as usual) or ad based image/links? Not sure i follow you there. Sorry it's not clear to me.

Comment: @t31os Sorry about that. Kinda didn't pay heed when following the script. I'll revise that a bit so hopefully it's a lot clearer. See the Twitter ad below as an example, though.

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep my eyes peeled for the update.. :)

Comment: @t31os Updated. The previous incarnation was pretty much a carbon copy from what we gave on Gaming, and... well, it wasn't very explanatory, haha.

Comment: So, once X many users have made submissions in this thread(and voted for the best) it will be rolled out and whenever a question fills the criteria that ad will be shown in the sidebar when an answer from a user hits that threshold? The update helped, but i still feel i don't understand to some degree(i'm quite a simple guy, so don't blame yourself for that)..

Comment: @t31os Whatever points confuse you are points we don't cover clear enough, so we have to fix. So think nothing bad of your critiques, they'll only help me revise this better. To answer your question - there is no requirement for X users or submissions. Any answer on this thread is game - all it needs to do is accumulate at least 6 upvotes. That will make it show up on the sidebar. The ads will be shown as part of the normal ad rotation, no special priority or privilege.

Comment: What got me caught up was with regard to the answer threshold, for some reason i thought that related to answers on the main site, though i realise now you were refering to answers specific to this question(not sure if that part was worded the same all along, so perhaps an error on my part)..

Comment: So the click-through URL points to whatever we deem useful / important, right? So i could for example, post an answer with my own image, and link that to something i think the community will benefit from. What if there are several things i think might be useful, should i submit the same image several times, but with a different click-through? (or would i need to submit multiple images for multiple links?).. Can the image not be rated seperately? I might submit a good image, but users may disagree with the click-through i choose, as an example..

Comment: @t31os Use an image that reflects what you're advertising. You're basically making an advertisement banner, just in the dimensions we're specifying. You pick what the ad looks like, and what the ad click goes to. You shouldn't be separating the image and the link - they're basically one in the same. Look at the Twitter ad as an example.

Comment: That makes sense, not sure why that wasn't clear to me before, thanks for clarifying, and the lightning response(do you get notified instantly? - always super fast to respond).. :)

Comment: @t31os It's my question, so I get notified of all comments on it. ♪

Comment: Just realized, that this also means _animated_ gifs, right?

Comment: @kaiser "Image requirements > No animated GIFs"

Answer (score 16):

[image: QueryPosts.com - better WordPress code reference]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Own a website? Join us over at webmasters.stackexchange.com]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]