# I have a new plugin I'd like to share, what's the best way to do so?

Tags: discussion

I published a new plugin to the plugins repo that I'm rather proud of and think it will be extremely helpful to developers, and I want to share it with the WPSE community. Is there an appropriate way to do so?

I tried to find discussions about this and came up empty. I found [one case of precedence](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/), but it seems like this might now be borderline off-topic as a plugin recommendations question.

Comment: LOL too much for the precedent, `"what a coincidence that you ask this, Jan!"` :))

Answer (score 9):

I would not use the Q&A system for that. It is allowed with some limitations. From [our FAQ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)

> #### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer  free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

But as a mod I can predict you will get spam flags very soon – often too soon.

There are alternatives:

### Your Profile

You can put almost anything into your profile. Yes, even bold promotion. Images, 500 links … whatever. It should be *safe for work* though.

### Community Ad

Create an image and [propose a community ad](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/community-promotion-ads-2013). Open source plugins are welcome here explicitly. If your proposal reaches a score of 6 your image with the link will be displayed in the sidebar of our main site.

Comment: Community ad is definitely the way to go.

Comment: i saw rarst's new wordpress code reference site there they are actually visible with adblock plus on - for now ;)

Answer (score 3):

If the plugin is inspired by, began as, or extends a WordPress Answers answer, there's the [WPSE Plugins thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18459/wpse-plugin-repository-the-plugins-that-came-out-of-wp-answers). That's a small sliver of all plugins, but it may be relevant for some plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the plugin, you can always send it over to us at [WPBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/) using the contact form. We do plugin writeups all the time.

Comment: _I want to share it with the WPSE community._ I think both audiences are very different.