# What about putting a link to the wordpress survey on the site?

Tags: discussion

As many of you know the 2013 wordpress survey is now available [here](http://wp-survey.polldaddy.com/s/wp-2013).

I feel that it is important to take some time to answer as it can improve the software, I also see it as a way of giving back.

I propose to put a link somehow somewhere on the WP site (maybe on the sidebar, either as an announcement or as an ad) since the value of the feed of this site's users is huge and very important for the community.

Comment: I can create community event, but I need specific date when it will end. Asked Nacin on Twitter...

Comment: Scratch that, cannot point SE community event to non-SE URL.

Comment: @Rarst I saw your tweet! Thats a pity! Cand de admins do anything about it or is it too much and exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems community events can only be internal links, so I cannot point one to survey URL.

You could create community ad for it, see: [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Comment: [Added](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/community-promotion-ads-2013/2539#2539)