# A dynamic community promotion ad for the current bounties

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Apple folks [were so kind as to share](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/how-does-the-active-bounties-banner-work/1875#1875) the following dynamic ad:

[image: This numbers is live as of NOW, UTC 2013-11-234 at 1:33]
<sub>*Number live as of NOW at WPSE, UTC 2013-11-24 at 1:33*</sub>

---

Yes, just go to any Stack Exchange site, open any post and paste the following as an Answer:

```
[![Our currently active bounties][1]][2]

  [1]: http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png "Our currently active bounties"
  [2]: http://CURRENT-SITE.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured
```

***It will render the current bounties in the current site.***

---

I tried to propose this at our [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1309/12615), but

> [image: meh, does not compute]

Comment: +1 That's a kool idea!

Comment: Yep, pretty juicy :) What about a bounty party when this goes live? 3k+ folks or whatever put 50 reps or whatever and we blow the ad to a BIG number.

Comment: Oh, right, the image has to be on a specific domain... Totally forgot about that limitation.

Comment: IIRC you can post with any random i.stack.imgur.com image, then edit the post and swap out the image with the bounty ad. They might have closed that loophole since we did it though.